# Kill screensaver and unlock a mac using appleScript

Tags: iphone, macos, bluetooth, applescript

I'm trying to unlock my mac using my iPhone via bluetooth proximity, the code I'm using:

```
tell application "System Events"
tell security preferences
    set require password to wake to false
end tell
end tell

tell application "ScreenSaverEngine" to quit
```

It kills the screensaver, doesn't show the password box but all I get is a black screen. All applications still running but I'm hovering the mouse on this black screen.
I'm running two monitors on a 10.6.7 build.
What's wrong? Thanks.

> lifehacker article http://lifehacker.com/5816791/use-a-bluetooth-phone-or-device-to-lock-and-unlock-your-mac-when-youre-near

Comment: I am having the same problem with the black screen. I am using OS X Lion. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Never, after some tests (also, never used that shell script) I gave up. I'm pretty sure this is an awesome thing to do, but nothing have worked properly.

Comment: Have same issue but seems the screensaver is off but I still been asked for password...Any help?

Answer (score 11):

You could try an alternative way to kill the screen saver, such as a shell script with

```
#!/bin/sh
killall ScreenSaverEngine
```

And calling it directly, or writing an applescript to call it if you'd like that for some reason to do with the lifehacker article.

Comment: Ok, not what I was expecting but thank you! That code is supposed to work, just like yours then?

Comment: I had typed the process name from memory last time and had it wrongly as "screensaver" (I was thinking of "xscreensaver" on a lot of linux distros). It should work with my edited version.

Comment: @shelhamer `killall ScreenSaverEngine` still generates a black screen for me.

Comment: Still works in 10.13.2 17C205 via ssh from another machine; needed because a KeyboardMaestro call to Lock Screen often leaves the screensaver unstoppable after unlocking.

Comment: This has proven useful for me, I'm not sure why it's happening, but I suspect Synergy is the one that is leaving my Macbook in such a weird state where it still shows the screen saver after re-doing the login to unlock it.

Comment: It doesn't work on Big Sur, what's the command there?